# Yeast bread "blow out" in the oven

Tags: bread

This question is not being answered because it appears to be a duplicate.  However, the answers provided for the other post on blow outs seem to apply to artisan breads.  I have never added moisture to my oven nor slashed my loaves when baking a yeast bread in a loaf pan nor has it ever been suggested in any recipes I have followed.  Please reconsider my question.  Thank you.
I bake yeast(not artisan or sourdough)in a loaf pan on a lower rack in a preheated 375 degree oven.  When I get a lovely oven spring, I also tend to get an ugly blowout.  I think my ingredient ratios are in line as I follow the recipes but also use "feel" to guide the end result:  Not too stiff but slightly on the sticky side.  I use a stand mixer for most of the kneading and then finish with gentle hand kneading.  I shape the loaves gently by hand and make sure the seams are all tucked into the bottom.  I try to adhere to the recommended rise times as well.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Even after your edit, it seems to me that the linked question provides the information you need to solve your problem.  A slash along the top of your loaf will allow for expansion without the "blow out."

Comment: Not the answer.  Moving on